# react native lint critical failed?

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, eslint, lint, npm-scripts

After running npm run lint:critical, it came back with one error, that is this:

```
61:26  error    Unexpected 'this'                                 no-invalid-this
```

the function ask for the user permission for location detection:

```
_askForPermission = async () => {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        dispatch($isLocationActive()).catch((error) => dispatch(Activity.$toast('failure', error.message)));
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };
```

the line const { dispatch } = this.props; is causing the error, and I need to fix because it is causing a fail at the pipeline CI/CD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't be passing dispatch to components. I think it would be better to create an action that does what you need it to and pass it into the component through `mapDispatchToProps`. Your component may look something like this:

```
import { toastError } from './actions'

class Foo extends Component {
  render() {
    _askForPermission = async () => {
      const { myNewPropFromAction } = this.props;
      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
          myNewPropFromAction()
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }
    };

    return (
      <div>Hello World</div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  myNewPropFromAction: toastError 
});

export default ({}, mapDispatchToProps)(Foo);
```